# how to place image in the middle of the container and two buttons on bottom

Tags: html, css, image, button, vertical-alignment

I am new to html and css. My question is how do I place image and two buttons to be sure that they will be displayed together? Look at the image to understand what i mean. Thanks!!!!

[Height alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POT1W.jpg)

Comment: Please try it yourself first. In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would be helpful if you could let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. Try opening the snippet in full screen, and then resize the browser.

When the width of the screen is greater than `768px`(u can change this value) the width of the `container` is `500px`.

And when the width is less, then the container takes full width of the screen.

This is handled by

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media(max-width:768px) { 
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

As for the buttons, their combined width will be always equal to that of the image.

This is handled by

```
.btn-container {
  font-size: 0;/*used for removing whitespace from inline elements*/
}

.btn-container button {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: initial;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media(max-width:768px) { /* can be any number less than this depending on ur choice */
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.btn-container {
  font-size: 0;
}

.btn-container button {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: initial;
  padding: 15px;
}


/*Space between */

.btn-holder {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-holder button {
  width: 100%;
}

.b1 {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.b2 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http:placehold.it/250x250">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button>button 1 </button>
    <button>button 1 </button>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<h3>If u want space between buttons</h3>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http:placehold.it/250x250">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <div class="btn-holder b1">
      <button>button 1 </button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-holder b2">
      <button>button 1 </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the image centering you can just use:

```
<div id="container">
  <img style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></img>
</div>
```

Then for the buttons you can use:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <button id="button1">button left</button>
    <button id="button2">button right</button>
</div>
```

and then this css:

```
#button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
#button2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
}
```

Which you then combine into this:

```css
    #button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
#button2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width:160px;
    height:160px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
      <img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fupload.wikimedia.org%2Fwikipedia%2Fcommons%2Fthumb%2F8%2F8f%2FExample_image.svg%2F1024px-Example_image.svg.png&f=1" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"></img>
      <br>
      <button id="button1">button left</button>
      <button id="button2">button right</button>
    </div>
```

in case you're confused as to what the `<br>` tag does it is just a line break in order to make sure that the buttons don't get placed next to the image.